# Trying to compute $k[X,U]/(X+U-a,XU)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $K$ is a field and $a\in K^{\times}$. I would like to compute the quotient $K[X,U]/(X+U-a,XU)$ and show that it is isomorphic to $K\times K$ as $K$-algebras. I thought to take the morphism of $K$-algebras $\varphi:K[X,U]/(X+U-a,XU)\rightarrow K\times K$ that maps $X$ to $(a,0)$ and $U$ to $(0,a)$, but I couldn't see that it is injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, your ring is isomorphic to $K[U]/(U(a-U))$. By Chinese Remainder Theorem $K[U]/(U(a-U))$ is isomorphic to $K[U]/(U)\times K[U]/(a-U)$, that is, to $K\times K$.